# Command doesn't run from shell script on remote windows machine: Unable to execute command or shell in remote system

Tags: shell, powershell, ssh, sshpass

I have a Windows Client machine and I would like to invoke a powershell script on that client from my local machine i.e. Mac.
I have ssh on Windows via freesshd.
Also, i need to provide password via script hence I ended up using sshpass.
From my Mac Terminal, while the command:

```
sshpass -v -p xxx ssh administrator@x.x.x.x "powershell.exe dir"
```

runs perfectly and returns the content of whatever directory the shell lands in, i am unable the get the same result from inside a shell script.

The simple script is as below:

```
cmd='sshpass -v -p xxx ssh administrator@x.x.x.x "powershell.exe dir"'
echo `$cmd`
```

What I get is:

> Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute
>   process.

I have tried various permutations of " and ' to get the correct command string but to no avail.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Why not install PowerShell on your Mac and use PowerShell Remoting?

Comment: its part of a test suite, hence must use a shell script.

Comment: You may need to inspect logs on the remote host then.